# Difference in pattern matching between Cases and ReplaceAll

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I don't understand why there is a difference in the pattern matching between

```
x a /. coef_*x^pow_. :> {pow, coef}
```

and

```
Cases[x a , coef_*x^pow_. :> {pow, coef}, Infinity, Heads -> True]
```

Should Cases not always find a match (if we specify infinite levelspec) if ReplaceAll does?

How do I get cases to "see" this pattern match?

Comment: Use All instead of Infinity, which is shorthand for `{0,Infinity}`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Interesting. When is this feature added? It doesn't seem to be mentioned in the document, and is not supported in _v9.0.1_.